# Is there a way to sort by difference in values between two columns

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that contains employee names, sales from current year, and sales from last year.  Lets call the two sales columns 2022 and 2021.  Im looking to sort my table by the highest difference between this year and last years sales.  For example, the highest difference would be at the top.

Currently I have it as

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT customerid,
    full_name,
    "2012 Sales",
    "2013 Sales"
FROM
    customer_loyalty
ORDER BY "2013 Sales" DESC
    limit 10;
```

Can i just insert a where conditon like 2013-2012 ASC?

Comment: Well, what happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT customerid,
    full_name,
    `2012 Sales`,
    `2013 Sales`
FROM
    customer_loyalty
ORDER BY 
  `2013 Sales` - `2012 Sales` DESC
LIMIT 10;
```